# "The idea of SO is to show people how to code not to code for them"

Tags: discussion, source-code

Comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416913/split-call-data-to-15-minute-intervals/5417245#5417245)

This question is simple - is it **wrong** to enjoy challenges and to provide properly tested code?  Properly tested code is provided not to satisfy "plz-give-me-teh-codez" but because a good example is IMHO one with working code, not one that does not even syntax check (flying under banner of *pseudo*).

I find that codified solutions are formal proof of the concept that would otherwise live only in pseudo (and easily misunderstood / unimplementable to certain skill levels).  **A picture paints a thousand words**; so does a good code block.

Interested in your thoughts.

Comment: I don't believe that, no such rules out there!

Answer (score 9):

You misinterpret that statement. Of course we're here to provide code...but we're not here to do the work for you. We're here to provide solutions to certain problems, not to provide you with a ready-to-use application. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, it's a question and answer community. If you've got a specific question about a problem, we'll provide the solution in coded form and/or in a documented way so that you can fix the problem yourself with ease.

This statement addresses questions like "What code do I need to write application x doing y?" or "Can you write me a program which does y?" (and my favorites: "Plz give me the codes to do y!"). Or people who just copy and paste the given (example) code and then comeback with "It's not working :(" without even thinking for a moment why (my personal favorites again: "This does throw an ArgumentNullException, why?"). If you feel like providing answers to such questions which should better be better send to a code writing service, please feel free to do so...but they're off-topic on Stack Overflow and should not be encouraged.

It's also not about how long the answer took to assemble...it's about why you need to assemble it in the first place. A good question has an outlined problem, a background, information about what was tried, already thought out possible solutions, provides additional information and is not like "Ohhh...my code throws an exception, I better ask on SO why.". It's about if the poster is willing to learn from and with us and not about "Copy and Paste" solutions.

But to be honest, I misunderstood the discussion and the context of the sentence in your link in the first place. But I still stick to my opinion, and the context suggests that he meant my "...documented way so that you can fix the problem yourself with ease."-thingy.

Comment: Can you sell 2 minutes of service, or 10 on those sites? What's the going rate? That is how long it took to construct my answer. How would you rather such a question be asked, which clearly is complex and relates to a specific problem? Would you rather spend 30 minutes on a teaching exercise explaining in excruciating detail and having long conversations instead of just leaving the answer up for self help and learning?

Comment: @Richard: I was trying to address exactly this (edited the second paragraph a little to address the situation in your example better): If it is a question to a specific problem and you're ready to think about the solution (thought provided by someone else), then there's no problem with that.

Comment: @Richard: I've edited my answer ones more...though, the answer of jzd boils down to one of the points I tried to say.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use code fences for `emphasis`...

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ Yeah, you're right. One of these days I will go through all my answers and fix them up...one fine days...

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with "to enjoy challenges and to provide properly tested code".   However, the comment from the post you linked is not in response to that question.   It is actually the complete opposite.  It is saying that complete and correct code is not required for SO.  Many times a simple pseudo-code that illustrates a point or a direction the OP needs to go in, is better than a completed tested solution.

Comment: I beg to differ. I was trying to compare the performance of the approaches (recursive CTE vs number sequence). The "directional" answer made it a very laborious exercise starting with fixing bugs, then discovering flaws in the answer (since it is not [tested-] codified - hard to pin down), so it is hard to even tell if the answer is viable.

Comment: @Richard, I think there is still some confusion here.  The "directional" answer is of course going to require more work to implement than a complete working solution, but if you can't tell if the answer is viable, don't upvote it and let the OP accept it if it works.  The OP will learn more from a "directional" answer because some assembly will be required.